# snapshot test with axios mock react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios

I have a component rendering a list of products pulled in from an axios.get call, I'm using mock axios and mock my data, feed that data into my test and snapshot the result but right now I'm getting some conflicting results. My main issue is that my snapshot does snap the entire rendered component rather it only snapshots the `Loading...` (which means the array is empty) state. I will take you through my debugging process.

```
 it('should render data', async () => {
    const mAxiosResponse = {
      data: testData.products,
    } as AxiosResponse;
    
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce(mAxiosResponse);
    const {getByTestId, getAllByTestId, getByText} = render(<Products />);
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument());
    await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('ContentTypeDropdown')).toBeInTheDocument());
    await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId('SortDropdown')).toBeInTheDocument());
    await waitFor(() => expect(getAllByTestId('navigation')).toHaveLength(2))
    expect(getByTestId('ContentTypeDropdown')).toHaveLength(21);
  });
```

In this test I'm using `jest.spyon` to mock my axios call and then wait for the results, first:

1. The axios call is mocked and the component will attempt to load
2. Ultimately it should load and I search for a component (ContentTypeDropdown) that should be present on load if the `jest.spyon` retreives the data, (`ContentTypeDropdown` this is a html  in the component below)
3. I completed various other assertions and they all Pass successfully!

This test runs succcesfully as the test can locate the elements on loaded on the page!

However now trying to rewrite the test above to cater for a snapshot as I don't want to assert every element on the page individually. Now it presents a problem as the snapshot is empty! and only returns `Loading...`

Rewritten test:

```
  it.only('should render data', async () => {
    const mAxiosResponse = {
      data: testData.products,
    } as AxiosResponse;
    
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce(mAxiosResponse);
    const tree = renderer.create(<Products />).toJSON();
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument());
   
    await waitFor(() => expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot());
  });
```

Snapshot result:

```
exports[`should render data 1`] = `
<div>
  Loading...
</div>
`;
```

which is confusing because the first iteration of this test definitely passed and told me it was able to locate elements on the page which means it moved past the `Loading...` state.

Ultimately I assumed it was a problem with my axios mock and so I rewrote the test again:

```
  it('should render data', async () => {
    const mAxiosResponse = {
      data: data,
    } as AxiosResponse;
    
    act(() => {
    (axios.get as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() =>  Promise.resolve({
      mAxiosResponse
    }) );
  })

    const tree = renderer.create(<Products />).toJSON();
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument());
    
    await waitFor(() => expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot());
  });
```

Unfortunately after all this debugging, I'm still getting an undesired snapshot result, it won't make it past the `Loading...` state even though the data is provided.

Can someone shed some light on this please?
I will provide the component I'm testing the better context:

Products.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { sortBy, sortSelectOptions } from '../utils/utils';
import { Products } from '../types/types';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import { fetchData } from '../endpoints/fetchData';
import { NoResults } from './NoResults';
import PlaceholderImage from '../../assets/spinner.gif';
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios'

import Select from './Select';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import '../index.css';

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Products[]>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [contentTypeValue, setContentTypeValue] = useState<string>('Stories');

  const productsPerPage = 20;
  const lastIndex = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - productsPerPage;
   const productsByContentType = products.filter((type: Products) => type.contentType.includes(contentTypeValue))  || products;
  const filteredProducts = sortBy?.[filterValue]?.(productsByContentType) ?? productsByContentType;
  
  const productsBySearchValue = filteredProducts.filter((search: Products) => {
    return search.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
  }) || filteredProducts;
  const currentProducts = productsBySearchValue.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
  const pages = Math.ceil(productsBySearchValue.length / productsPerPage);
  const numbers = [...Array(pages + 1).keys()].slice(1);

  const fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3030/products')
      .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
        setProducts(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    setSearchValue('');
  }, []);


  if(products.length === 0) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  const nextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== lastIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(curr => curr + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== firstIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(curr => curr - 1);
    }
  };

  const movePages = (id: number) => {
    setCurrentPage(id);
  };


  //Generate content type list
  const transformContentTypeintoList = [
    ...new Set(products.map((prod) => prod.contentType).flat()),
  ];

  const contentTypeList = transformContentTypeintoList
    .map((item) =>  [
        {
          label: item,
          value: item,
        },
      ])
    .flat();

  const handleSort = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setFilterValue(event?.target.value);
    //goto page 1 after sort
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleTitleSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
        setSearchValue(value.toLowerCase());
        setCurrentPage(1)
  };

  const handleContentTypeSort = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setContentTypeValue(value) 
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const mapContentTypes = () => {
    return (
      <Select
        id="contentSelect"
        options={contentTypeList}
        datatestid={'ContentTypeDropdown'}
        onChange={handleContentTypeSort}
        defaultOption={'Select Content Type'}
        label={'Filter by Content type '}
      />
    );
  };
 
  const mapProducts = () => {
    if (currentProducts.length === 0) {
      return <NoResults />;
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="searchContainer">
            <TextInput
              className="searchInput"
              placeholder="search by title"
              value={searchValue}
              datatestid={'searchId'}
              onChange={handleTitleSearch}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="filterContainer">
              <div>
                <Pagination
                  numbers={numbers}
                  currentPage={currentPage}
                  prevPage={prevPage}
                  movePages={movePages}
                  nextPage={nextPage}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="filter">
                {mapContentTypes()}
                <Select
                  id="SortSelect"
                  options={sortSelectOptions}
                  datatestid={'SortDropdown'}
                  onChange={handleSort}
                  defaultOption={'Sort by'}
                  label={'Sort by '}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            {currentProducts.map((product: Products) => {
              return (
                <div className="item" key={product.id}>
                  <img
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                    loading='lazy'
                    src={product.imgSet.sm.src}
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <div
                    aria-label={`Product${product.id}`}
                    tabIndex={0}
                    className="innerContainer">
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Name`}>
                      Name: {product.title}
                    </span>
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Price`}>
                      Price: {product.price}
                    </span>
                    <span
                      className="text"
                      tabIndex={0}
                      aria-label={` Stock level`}>
                      Stock level: {product.productType}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <Pagination
              numbers={numbers}
              currentPage={currentPage}
              prevPage={prevPage}
              movePages={movePages}
              nextPage={nextPage}
            />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className="container">{mapProducts()}</div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default App;
```